# How to select one of the user defined table rows if other data type is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two user defined table type in SQL server 2012 table `@Table1` with column name as `ColumnTable1` and `@Table2` with one of the columns as `ColumnTable2`.

I wish to select data from a physical table named `employeeData`. This table has both the columns(`ColumnTable1` and `ColumnTable2` in it).

What I want is when both `@table1` and `@table2` have data, then values matching from the both the UDT in `employeeData` should be returned. If only one of them, then values matching from that table should be returned and if both are null, then all the data from `Employeedata` table must be returned.

I tried a query which works fine of both of them are not null.

```sql
SELECT * FROM employeeData WHERE
         (((NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Table1) OR ColumnTable1 IN (SELECT 
         ColumnTable1 FROM @Table1)) AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Table2) 
         OR ColumnTable2 in (SELECT ColumnTable2 FROM @Table2)))
```

PS: this example is for only two tables, I may need to add new such user defined tables in future for similar filtering.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and expected output. I think this will help clarify the third paragraph in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select t.*
from employeeData t
left join @Table1 t1 on t1.ColumnTable1 =t.ColumnTable1 
left join @Table2 t2 on t2.ColumnTable2 =t.ColumnTable2
where 
not (t1.ColumnTable1 is null and exists (select top 1 1 from @Table1))
and
not (t2.ColumnTable2 is null and exists (select top 1 1 from @Table2))
```

Comment: Hi, it's working perfectly and I hope that we can just include new filters using similar left joins and repeating `and
not (t2.ColumnTable2 is null and exists (select top 1 1 from @Table2))`. I just have a couple of questions. won't using too many joins affect the performance of the query? (my requirement can scale up to 1 dozen user-defined table type.) Additionally, how does the keyword `not` satisfies the conditions? Sorry I am new to SQL. Thanks!!

Comment: If you found it useful, please accept the answer. If you need to add conditions you have not many other options, but if you put the right indexes on tables (both physical and variable) your performances will be very good anyway.

Comment: the keyword `NOT` is simply the boolean negation of what follow. In this case you can read it like: `ColumTable1 is not null` (it means @Table1 is not empty and there is a match) **OR** (because not(A and B) = (not A or not B )) `@Table1` is empty